# Making a string sequence

Tags: java

I need to Write a method called MakeSequence that takes in a single integer parameter N and produces and returns a String sequence.
For Example MakeSequence(5) would return a String consisting of “555554444333221”.
If the input parameter N is less than 1 then an empty String should be returned (NOT null).

This is what I have tried, but the problem is that this returns the string and the empty string, I don't want to return the empty string. How would I go about doing this?

```
public static String MakeSequence(int N)
    {
        String repeat = "";
        if (N>0)
        {
            repeat = String.valueOf(N);
            for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
            {
                System.out.print(repeat);
            }
            return MakeSequence(N-1);
        }
        else
        {
            return repeat;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
public static String MakeSequence(int N) {
      if(N < 1) return "";
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = N; i > 0 ; i--) {
          builder.append(String.valueOf(i).repeat(i));
      }

      return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `StringBuilder` to concatenate a string very quickly.

The problem you didn't concatenate the string right

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = makeSequence(new StringBuilder(), 5);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static String makeSequence(StringBuilder builder, int N) {
        if (N > 0) {
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                builder.append(N);
            }
            return makeSequence(builder, N - 1);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

, `output`

```
555554444333221
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition the other answer ....If you dont need the recursion you can also do it in a loop. ([java11 repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)))

```
private static String callMe(int counter) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int y = counter ; y > 0 ;y--){
        result.append(String.valueOf(y).repeat(y));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [`IntStream#iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate(int,java.util.function.IntPredicate,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)) to create a sequence of integers from `5` to `1`, then repeat the String using [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) as of Java 11 and finally collect using [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining())?

```
String string = IntStream.iterate(5, i -> i > 0, i -> i- 1)          // 5 to 0 (excl.)
                         .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i).repeat(i)) // repeat i i-times
                         .collect(Collectors.joining());             // concatenate
```

```
System.out.println(string);             // 555554444333221
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a number of nice answers here, but just for fun here's another purely recursive approach. Not efficient obviously, but quite pretty.

```
public static String makeSequence(int n)
{
    return makeSequence(new StringBuilder(), n, n);
}

private static String makeSequence(StringBuilder b, int n, int m)
{
    if (m > 0) 
        return makeSequence(b.append(n), n, m-1);
    
    if (n > 0) 
        return makeSequence(b, n-1, n-1);
    
    return b.toString();
}
```